# Shared Server cum VPS

Tags: hosting, web-deployment, war, vps, shared-hosting

I am working on dynamic web application for hosting on Internet. Since this is a java based application, so Tomcat server is required on hosting.
So, can anyone please tell me about Shared **VPS server**, for deployment of .war? And how to configure **Tomcat on shared VPS**?